# Change the language text variables in the optidef package

Tags: babel, optidef

How can I change the language of the optidef package.

Specifically I would like to redefine the "minimize" and "subject to" text variables:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, optidef}

\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert_2}

\begin{document}

\begin{mini!}[short]
  {x}{ \norm{f(x)}^2 \label{eq:optProb}}{}{}
\addConstraint{\alpha + (\beta*\gamma)}{ \geq 0,\label{eq:constraint1}}
\addConstraint{\beta}{\geq 0.\label{eq:constraint2}}
\end{mini!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: One minor optimization would be getting rid of one of the commas in `(1b)`.

Answer (score 1):

> Disclaimer: this feels like the wrong way to change things....

The words `subject~to` are hard coded in the package .sty file, but you can redefine the `\bodySubjectToDefinition` macro. In the following example change the `xxx~subject~to` to whatever language you like.

Same for the `mini!` environment. Change `zzz~minimize` in the example below.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, optidef}

\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert_2}

\renewcommand{\localOptimalVariable}{sfds}

\renewcommand{\bodySubjectToDefinition}{
%## If the short version of "subject to", i.e. "s.t.", should be used the command \bodySubjectTo should be modified
\ifthenelse{\equal{\localProblemFormat}{s}}
{%%
\global\def\bodySubjectTo{\mathmakebox[\widthof{$\underset{\displaystyle \phantom{\localOptimalVariable}}{\mathrm{\localProblemType}}$}][c]{\mathmakebox[\widthof{$\mathrm{\localProblemType}$}][l]{\mathrm{\kern 0.1em s.t.}}}}
}{%%
\global\def\bodySubjectTo{\mathmakebox[\widthof{$\underset{\displaystyle \phantom{\localOptimalVariable}}{\mathrm{\,sucbject~to}}$}][c]{\mathmakebox[\widthof{$\mathrm{\localProblemType}$}][l]{\mathrm{xxx~subject~to}}}}
}%%
%
}

% Multiple reference
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{mini!}{D||{\defaultProblemFormat} O{\defaultConstraintFormat} D<>{} m m m m}
{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{s}}
    % Short version problem
    {\setFormatShort{min}{#2} \BaseMiniExclam{#2}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{min}{#3}}
    % Long version problem  
    {\setFormatLong{minimize}{#2} \BaseMiniExclam{#2}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{zzz~minimize}{#3}}
}{\endBaseMiniExclam\toggletrue{bodyCon}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mini!}[short]
  {x}{ \norm{f(x)}^2 \label{eq:optProb}}{}{}
\addConstraint{\alpha + (\beta*\gamma)}{ \geq 0,\label{eq:constraint1}}
\addConstraint{\beta}{\geq 0.\label{eq:constraint2}}
\end{mini!}

\end{document}
```